# Eigenvectors corresponding to zero valued eigenvalues are different between eigen and prcomp in R

Tags: r, pca

I was trying out the prcomp function in R to calculate the principal components for some test design matrix below (purposefully made multicollinear), with the output:

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(30,1,3)
test2 = data.frame(x = x, x2 = 2*x+integer(30)+1, x3 = 3*x)
pr.out2 = prcomp(test2)
pr.out2

Standard deviations (1, .., p=3):
[1] 1.037323e+01 1.964168e-15 5.867005e-16

Rotation (n x k) = (3 x 3):
         PC1        PC2        PC3
x  0.2672612  0.3683640  0.8904378
x2 0.5345225 -0.8255282  0.1810769
x3 0.8017837  0.4275642 -0.4175305
```

Using the eigen function on the covariance matrix of the same test2 above, I get the following:

```
eigen(cov(test2))
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1] 1.076039e+02 2.842171e-14 0.000000e+00

$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.2672612  0.9636241  0.0000000
[2,] -0.5345225 -0.1482499 -0.8320503
[3,] -0.8017837 -0.2223748  0.5547002
```

As expected, the first eigenvector matches the first principal component from prcomp (up to the sign) and the leading eigenvalue is equal to the standard deviation square from prcomp first princpal component.

Since I made x2 and x3 linear functions of x1, I expected two zero eigenvalues, which are confirmed by the output by both prcomp and eigen. However, I noticed that the last two eigenvector from eigen and the last two principal component (corresponding to the zero eigenvalue) does not match. I suspect that because the zero eigenvalue has multiplicity of 2, I have a plane of eigenvectors orthogonal to the first principal component and the two functions computes them differently under the hood, is this correct?

Comment: There are infinitely many eigenvectors for each eigenvalue. As long as the given eigenvectors for each eigenvalue span the same subspace, there is no bug. In the case of eigenvalue `0`, the eigenspace is the same as the kernel of the linear transformation. As long as in each case you have two linearly independent non-zero vectors which map to `0`, you are okay.